# Hipervínculo en SVG

Tags: html

¿Cuál es la manera correcta de insertar un hipervínculo a un path de SVG?.
Tengo entendido que no se debe realizar esto

```
<svg>
   <a href="#">
      <path>
   </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: Que es precisamente lo que intentas hacer? Si quieres que un SVG sea un enlace, porque no usar la etiqueta `a` como contenedor para el SVG?

Comment: Revisa la respuesta dada en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968082/how-to-add-a-link-inside-an-svg-circle):

Comment: @IvanS95 Quiero que dentro de un SVG las etiquetas path tengan diferente enlace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira en https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <!-- A link around a shape -->
  <a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/247788">
    <circle cx="50" cy="40" r="35"/>
  </a>

  <!-- A link around a text -->
  <a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/93294">
    <text x="50" y="90" text-anchor="middle">
      &lt;circle&gt;
    </text>
  </a>
</svg>
```